# Is projection onto a convex set strictly contractive when one point is in the set?

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization

Given a nonempty closed convex set $S\in\mathbb{R}^n$, its projection operator, defined as
$$
p(x)= \textrm{argmin}_{z \in S} \| x - z\|_2
$$
for $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$, is unique and sends each $x$ to its unique nearest point in $S$. We know that projection onto such $S$ is a nonexpansive map, *i.e.,*
$$
\|p(x) - p(x)\|_2 \leq \|x-y\|_2,
$$
for all $x,y \in \mathbb{R}^n$. However, if one of the point  $y$ is already in $S$ (*i.e.,* $p(y)=y$), and the other point $x$ is not in $S$, then is $p(\cdot)$ (strictly) contractive? In other words, do we have
$$
\|p(x)-y\|_2 < \|x-y\|_2
$$
when $y\in S$ and $x \notin S$?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Answer (score 2):

True. Projections onto closed convex sets in Hilbert spaces are *firmly non-expansive*, i.e.,
\begin{equation} 
 \| p(x) - p(y) \|^2+\| (I-p) (x) - (I-p) (y)\|^2 \leq \| x-y \|^2
\end{equation}
So that if $ y \in S $, we have
\begin{equation} 
 \| p(x) - y \|^2 \leq  \| x-y \|^2-\| x-p(x) \|^2
\end{equation}
which means
\begin{equation} 
 \| p(x) - y \| <  \| x-y \|
\end{equation}
whenever $x \not\in S$

Comment: This is such a neat proof! Thanks so much @JJJ !